# Amazon SQS End of Queue Detection

Tags: amazon-sqs

I was wondering if there was a best practice for notifying the end of an sqs queue. I am spawning a bunch of generic workers to consume data from a queue and I want to notify them that they can stop processing once they detect no more messages in the queue. Does sqs provide this type of feature?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? If so, what about it did you find unclear?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the right_aws ruby gem source code for SQS I found that there is the ApproximateNumberOfMessages attribute on a queue. Which you can request using a standard API call.

You can find more information including examples here:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Query_QueryGetQueueAttributes.html

For more information on how to do this using the right_aws gem in ruby look at:

- https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws/blob/master/lib/sqs/right_sqs_gen2_interface.rb#L187
- https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws/blob/master/lib/sqs/right_sqs_gen2_interface.rb#L389

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "is there a way for the producer to notify consumers that it has finished sending messages?" .  If so, then no there isn't.   If a consumer calls "ReceiveMessage" and gets nothing back, or "ApproximateNumberOfMessages" returns zero, that's not a guarantee that no more messages will be sent or even that there are no messages in flight. And the producer can't send any kind of "end of stream" message because only one consumer will receive it, and it might arrive out of order.  Even if you used a separate notification mechanism such as an SNS topic to notify all consumers, there's no guarantee that the SNS notification won't arrive before all the messages have been delivered.

But if you just want your pool of workers to back off when there are no messages left in the queue, then consider setting the "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds" property on your queue to its maximum value of 20 seconds.  When there are no more messages to process, a ReceiveMessage call will block for up to 20s to see if a message arrives instead of returning immediately.

You could have whatever's managing your thread pool query ApproximateNumberOfMessages to regularly scale/up down your thread pool if you're concerned about releasing resources.  If you do, then beware that the number you get back is Approximate, and you should always assume there may be one or more messages left on the queue even if ApproximateNumberOfMessages returns zero.